# escribir en una nueva columna con una variable ya definida python

Tags: python, python-3.x

hola que tal estoy teniendo un problema quiera guardar un numero en un txt realmente funcionar lo que es funcionar funciona ya que lo pone así:
1('\n', 1)('\n', ('\n', 1))
en vez de asi:
1
1
1
el codigo es el siguiente:

```
archivo = open("informacion.txt",'w')
a = 1
archivo.writelines(str(a))
a = "\n", a
b = "\n", a
archivo.writelines(str(a))
archivo.writelines(str(b))
archivo.close()
```

Comment: no se hizo bien la pregunta me refiero a poner los 1 en lineas separadas y en vez hacerlo me aparece todo esto en una misma 1('\n', 1)('\n', ('\n', 1))

Comment: Abajo de las etiquetas está el botón de editar por si quieres arreglar la pregunta :D

Comment: Sobre tu error, estás convirtiendo la tupla en cadena (lo que crea una cadena que representa una tupla) y luego la estás escribiendo. Simplemente quita el str de los writelines.

Comment: @DanteS. son numeros no puedo quitar str ya que me sale el siguiente error TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: En ese caso, convierte en cadenas el contenido de la tupla.

Comment: Si colocas una coma en el valor de una variable entonces edtas creando una tupla (a menos que hagas asignación múltiple). Si quieres concatenar strings entonces usa el `+`, por ejemplo `a = '\n' + a` o puedes usar *f-strings*

Comment: @Christian me parece que es la intención crear una tupla. Writelines acepta una tupla.

Answer (score 1):

En Python, asignar dos o más valores a una variable se considera como tupla:

```py
>>> a = 3, '\n'
>>> print(type(a), a)
<tuple>, (3, '\n')
```

Entonces:

```py
archivo = open("informacion.txt",'w')
a = 1
archivo.writelines(str(a))
archivo.writelines('\n') # <-- Escribe un un salto de línea
a = str(a) + "\n" # <-- Concatena un string con un salto
b = f"{a}\n" # <-- Otra forma de concatenar un string con un salto
archivo.writelines(a)
archivo.writelines(b) # <-- a es "1\n", entonces b es "1\n\n"
archivo.close()
```

Eso genera un archivo con un `1` en cada línea con un doble salto al final.